# Problemas ao dar run em projeto grails

Tags: grails, groovy

Criei um projeto novo aqui e estou tendo problemas para dar `run`, estou usando como `ide` o `plugin` de `grails` para o `eclipse`, ele não atesta erro nenhum no código porem ao tentar executar recebo o seguinte erro:

```
Error starting Grails: nulljava.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.<clinit>(InvokerHelper.java:61)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.<init>(GroovyObjectSupport.java:32)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.<init>(Closure.java:219)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.<init>(Closure.java:236)
    at groovy.lang.Closure$1.<init>(Closure.java:203)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.<clinit>(Closure.java:203)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.<clinit>(GrailsScriptRunner.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:263)
Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Conflicting module versions. Module [groovy-all is loaded in version 2.3.1 and you are trying to load version 2.3.3
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl$DefaultModuleListener.onModule(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:509)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanExtensionModuleFromProperties(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:78)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanExtensionModuleFromMetaInf(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:72)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanClasspathModules(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:71)
    at groovy.lang.GroovySystem.<clinit>(GroovySystem.java:33)
    ... 14 more
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu já tive esse problema no Grails...eu corrigi fazendo assim:

```
1 - Abra o Eclipse
2 - Vá em "Run as..."
3 - "Run Configurations"
4 - Escolha "Enviroment tab"
5 - Depois "Replace native enviroment with native enviroment"
6 - Tente rodar de novo e pronto :D
```